# How to fetch image from database in drupal

Tags: media

Let me know how to fetch image from database. actually i am trying to fetch image from database using this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18817/db-query-to-retrieve-the-image-path-using-the-fid).
I am try to fetch image from database using following code.
$fid is my $row['column_name']

```
 $fid=$r['field_upload_photo_fid'];
 $image = theme('image_style', array(
'style_name'=> 'small', 
'path' => $file->uri, 
'alt' => 'user picture'
 ));
 print $image;
```

Actual file url is http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/Style_name/public/Chrysanthemum.jpg

but now it shows http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/small/public/styles/Style_name/public/Chrysanthemum.jpg.
 thats why image not fetching from database.

Also what is a style in $variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace 'Style_name' with an actual image style, then it should work. That's because the function you are using does not only fetch the url of the image, it actually tries to fetch the image for a particular style, not the original.

Per default drupal ships with the image styles 'thumbnail', 'medium' and 'large'. You get these names when going to 'admin/config/media/image-styles', open the style you want to use for your image and look at the machine name - that's the 'style_name' you need.

So in your above example use for example:

```
$variables = array(
 'path' => $file->uri,
 'style_name'=>'medium'
);
```

You can use a custom image style as well of course.

---

**Edit:**

From the comments I guess you do not actually want to retrieve the url for a styled image, but the original url of the image. Here is the code which should retrieve the file url:

```
$fid=$r['field_upload_photo_fid'];
$file = file_load($fid);
$url_to_your_file = file_create_url($file->uri);
```

Comment: after putting medium url is http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/Medium/public/styles/Style_name/public/Chrysanthemum.jpg?itok=VgdqHeLy

Comment: That's alright. When using the url drupal will generate the image with the measures on the 'medium' image style - per default 220x220 pixel. Do you want an image style at all or do you actually just want the original? Your code is for returning the url for a particular imagestyle

Comment: the generated url is wrong thats why problem is create

Comment: It is not wrong. Drupal creates an own directory for each image style, filling it with the correctly sized and cropped images. If you want the original image url just use the file_create_url() function.

Comment: actually problem is generated url is not right thats why the image path is wrong

Comment: As I said - for a styled image the url is correct. However I edited my above answer to return the url to the original image as that's what you probably want.

Comment: Yes , finally i got url now i can use them into img src tag

Answer (score 0):

The style is an image style which is described a bit in [Working with images in Drupal 7 and 8](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/image). I believe that you need to use Style_name as the `'style'` in your code instead of `'public'`:

```
 $fid=$r['field_upload_photo_fid'];
 $file = file_load($fid);
 $variables = array(
 'path' => $file->uri,
 'style'=>'Style_name'
 );
 print theme('image_style', $variables);
```

But also, what is the data in `$file->uri`? If you start with bad data then the result is also going to be bad.

Comment: after putting Style_name the url is http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/public/styles/Style_name/public/Chrysanthemum

Comment: I dont know about $file->uri?.I just simple copy paste the code

Comment: let me know what is a Style_name